# How would I convert this code to pure CSS or Use this code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

```
@function multiple-box-shadow ($n) 
  $value: '#{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'
  @for $i from 2 through $n
    $value: '#{$value} , #{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF'

  @return unquote($value)

$shadows-small:  multiple-box-shadow(700)
$shadows-medium: multiple-box-shadow(200)
$shadows-big:    multiple-box-shadow(100)
```

**Explanation**

This code is supposedly supposed to produce random {START} like balls on as the backdrop when finished, I just can't seem to use Scss and would like to see if it can be still be created using a different method

Comment: CSS has no `random()` functionality (as far as I know)

Comment: so the original code is wrote in Scss or Sass I think,  is their a way reproduce this in javascript maybe? or would you need to see more code to understand

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use Javascript.  You can dynamically create the stylesheet in code.

Comment: Run your code in an online Sass interpreter like https://www.sassmeister.com/ (which I found in seconds using "sass playground"). You'll need to use the variables you created in a `box-shadow` property under a selector in order for them to be output in CSS.

Comment: Would you know  how to convert that code into a Javascript function instead?

Comment: _"I just can't seem to use Scss and would like to see if it can be still be created using a different method"_ Why not? It's probably much simpler to convert your project to CSS than to write a JavaScript logic to emulate it. And the performance will be better. You could even try to use a find-and-replace command like [`sed`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html).

Comment: I'm just having trouble using that @function in Scss, I think it's because of improper syntax but still can't figure out the right syntax

Comment: The problem could be that you call this code SCSS but it's actually SASS. That's two different syntaxes https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax.

Comment: You can google `sass compiler online` and play it there :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, the right syntax for your .scss would be like this:

```
@function multiple-box-shadow ($n) {
  $value: '#{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF';
  @for $i from 2 through $n {
    $value: '#{$value} , #{random(2000)}px #{random(2000)}px #FFF';
    }
  @return unquote($value);
}

$shadows-small:  multiple-box-shadow(700);
$shadows-medium: multiple-box-shadow(200);
$shadows-big:    multiple-box-shadow(100);

p{
  box-shadow: $shadows-small;
}
```

you can try to put this code in the compiler https://www.sassmeister.com/ to check it.
Other than that, if you need to use simple .css and put a random shadow, I think, you need to use JS.

Comment: The original syntax was fine for SASS, not SCSS. You can use SASS at SassMeister.